# Парсинг с сайта с одинаковыми тегами на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

учусь парсингу, хотелось бы узнать как парсить одинаковые теги.
Понятно что по id.
Проверял по print(div), информацию о всех id выводит правильно, мне нужно вывести именно нужную информацию c сайта.

```
import requests,bs4

mass_id =['bd1', 'bd2', 'bd3', 'bd4','bd5','bd6','bd7']#создаем массив для перебора вариантов

pogoda=requests.get('https://sinoptik.com.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0')#получение кода web-странцы в html
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(pogoda.text, "html.parser")
# select возвращает список всех найденных тегов с заданным селектором

for i in mass_id:
    div = soup.find('div', id=i)
    p1 = soup.select('.id .day-link')
    day_link=p1[0].getText()
    p2 = soup.select('.id .date')
    date = p2[0].getText()
    p3 = soup.select('.id .month')
    month = p3[0].getText()
    p4 = soup.select('.id .temperature .min')
    min = p4[0].getText()
    p5 = soup.select('.id .temperature .max')
    max = p5[0].getText()
    print('Дата: ' + date + ' ' + day_link + '\n' + 'Температура: ' + min + ' ' + max)
```

Comment: Что за "нужную информацию"? Чем она отличается от ненужной?

Comment: Он выводит полность html-код по заданному id

Comment: А надо что бы он выводил только текст из классов которые лежат в этом id

Answer (score 3):

Что такое `select`? Первый раз вижу. Парсинг здорового человека:

```
# page_html содержит content объекта Requests короче HTML-страницу
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
subject_url_soups = page_soup.find('div', class_='catalog-list').find_all('div', class_='item_table')
```

метод `find` возвращает объект, у которого ты можешь брать свойства (`text`, `href` etc), а метод `find_all` возвращает список. Обрати внимание на `class_`. Вот такие цепочки можно строить:

```
for subject_url_soup in subject_url_soups:
    subject_url = subject_url_soup.find('div', сlass_='description').find('h3').find('a').get('href')
    print(subject_url)
```

Как-то так. А вообще, я бы на твоём месте вообще начал с изучения структуры сайта, какие теги в какие вложены, как найти нужную инфу в DOM, как однозначно указать скрипту на нужный тег, и потом только приступал бы к написанию кода. Собственно, когда-то я тоже парсеры писал :) а по bs4 есть [неплохая методичка](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), по которой я сам в своё время изучал парсинг. Удачи!

Comment: `Что такое select? Первый раз вижу.` это функция для написания поиска через css-селекторы. Например, ваш поиск `page_soup.find('div', class_='catalog-list').find_all('div', class_='item_table')` тоже самое, что `page_soup.select('div.catalog-list div.item_table')`. Кст, это `'.id .day-link'` говорит что нужно искать элементы с `class='day-link'` которые находятся внутри элементов `class='id'` (причем не обязательно будут прямыми детьми, в отличии от `'.id > .day-link'`)

Comment: @gil9red да я образно написал. Просто в своё время решил что неудобно через `select` и юзал везде `find` и `find_all`

Comment: Согласен, `find` бывает удобнее и нагляднее, но это от ситуации зависит :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)